# there has been an error processing your request magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.6, magento

There has been an error processing your request magento 1.7
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1116398732

Someone has a solution for this error? Please solve my problem

Comment: You should be able to view more information about the error in var/log/exceptions.log

Comment: also if you change #ini_set('display_errors', 1); to ini_set('display_errors', 1); inside index.php it will give you some more details.

Answer (score 0):

report number represent specific files in var/report folder in magento root

open var/report/ in your magento root dir,
open file called same as your report number , in this case: '1116398732'
paste contents here and we will proceed with finding out what was wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can check the report by going to /var/report

Usually it occurs because of uncleared cache. Just go to /var/cache and delete all the files in cache folder. Refresh the page, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**There are three simple steps to resolve this issue**:
1- create tmp directory in your magento site
2- go to magento site/errors directory and update local.xml.sample to local.xml
3- go to magento site/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php and replace 'cache_dir' => null, to 'cache_dir' => 'tmp',
**NOTE:***tmp directory permission should be #777*

Answer (score 0):

Delete the generated/code directory rm -rf generated/code
Then run
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmo -R 0777 var/ pub/ generated/

Now try to run the site, it should be perfect now. Cheers

Comment: This doesn't seem to be relevant to the question as the answer you've given is specific to Magento 2.x and not 1.7